# GWT Context2d lineWidth

Tags: java, gwt

Im trying to draw lines (GWT, Context2d) that are 1 pixel thick, code snippet below:

```
context.beginPath();
context.setStrokeStyle("rgb(255,0,0)");
context.setLineWidth(1f);
double x = 0;
double gridSize = 10.0f;
while (x < w){
    x += gridSize;
    context.moveTo(x, 0);
    context.lineTo(x, h);
}
context.stroke();
```

This code draws lines that are at least 2 pixel thick.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add 0.5 to your coordinates. 
Browsers apply antialiasing this may cause blurriness or "2 pixel thick lines".